# No matching tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I found [this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/124003/fast-boot-up-on-imx6) which has a wrong tag. It's basically because the author didn't know what the `fastboot` tag stands for and have chosen it. However I didn't find any tags which are good for this question. As far as I know the author can't choose no tag, it's forbidden. So what should be done if you don't find any tag where your question fit into. I mean, you can't just choose a wrong tag with the thought "there is no better tag, but I can't change that".

I don't know if I'm at the right place here, probably some would say, I should post this in meta android but I think it's a general SE question what to do if no tag is good for your question.

Thank you in advance, moderators!

P.S.: Same thing here, I can't post a question with just the `tag` tag. I have to choose under these "bug feature-request discussion support". It's not bad that you don't want to have every content in the Meta SE, but I think you didn't do it right. currently this would make many content get labeled as `discussion` just to get it posted.

Comment: I've re-tagged it `boot` and `performance`, that should match the issue. Thanks for bringing it up!

Comment: For a quick reading why some tags are required in Meta, please read [What's Meta?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)

Answer (score 5):

When,

- you don't understand which tag is best for the question and all the current tags on the question are not suitable,
- when some current tags on the question are not suitable and you can't find a better one

but you still think a better tag is needed, then,

- with careful consideration (analyze the question thoughtfully) create a new tag or more -- [requires minimum of 300 reputation points](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags)
- the better choice: *ask the veterans*. Veterans may not necessarily be those only who've been with the site for a long time but can also be those who are  one or more year old here but are very good and active in editing questions.

I myself tend to be in situations when I do not understand what tag is best and I do not find it good to create  new tag(s) unless I'm sure there exists no other suitable tag. So I simply post the question on the site's [chatroom](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/badges/35/unsung-hero) with a brief note of the requirement and let the others take care of it.

If the user activity is low on chatroom then you can consider posting a comment on the question like:

> For users: The current tags on the question doesn't properly give the hint about the question, neither the question is actually about them. But I can't think of any better tag as of now, so may be one of you can consider an edit with a better tag. Thanks!

That has been my strategy. You can find your own or may be somebody else would propose a better one.

---

As for the meta tags, I'm not placed at best position to comment, but I respectfully disagree with your view about them. Meta isn't a place to  post anything, but it's all about the working of the main site, be it technical or user-centric issue.

If you look at your question again, you're are asking for best practices on what to be done when tags are not suitable and more....

[discussion](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion) tag exactly fits the question. See its excerpt. It's meant to seek community consensus on an issue.

If you're not seeking consensus then either you've a problem in using the site which goes into [support](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support), or there is an erroneous behavior you noticed which obviously fits [bug](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug), or you want a new feature, so [feature-request](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) goes here.

Also, if you think that the current mandatory tags doesn't cover everything or most of the issues, then it's better to propose a *proper and detailed* use-case and then argue with why the current mandatory meta tags doesn't fit the use-case yet the use-case as a question is useful. This would give us a better picture of what's going on in your mind since I (as a normal user), as noted, doesn't find an issue with the mandatory tags. *So, how would you convince the users like me?*

But reserve the use-case for another question.

Comment: Thank you! I also thought about creating a new tag (or in my case, ask for the creation), but I think it's not necessary to create a tag for one specific question. and yes, I am asking for best practices, so I don't understand why mods did move that.

Comment: If the condition demands then you've to create a tag at some point, though this point shouldn't be the priority. As for why this question was migrated back,  I can't tell for sure, neither would I attempt to. :) Perhaps Mods here or other users can guess.